# v-model won't detect changes made by jQuery trigger event

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, jquery-events

With Vue.js I'm using jQuery [Tempus Dominus](https://tempusdominus.github.io/bootstrap-4/) datepicker.

```
<input type="text"
       class="form-control datetimepicker-input"
       id="confirmedDueDate"
       data-target="#confirmedDueDate"
       @focus="openDatetimePicker($event)"  //to show the datetimepicker
       @blur="closeDateTimePicker($event)"  //to close it
       v-model="taskSettings.confirmedDueDate"
       />
```

I'm facing the following issue: `v-model` won't detect changes made by the `datetimepicker`.

I thought I could trigger an event when closing the picker with :

```
$('#confirmedDueDate').trigger('change');
//or
$('#confirmedDueDate').trigger('input');
```

but with this is not working.

Is there a known workaround for such cases?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The command

```js
$('#confirmedDueDate').trigger('input');
```

Triggers a [**`jQuery.Event` Object**](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) which Vue will not recognize, since it only knows native DOM events.

You can trigger "manually" an event that Vue will respond to using:

```js
$('#confirmedDueDate')[0].dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('input'));
```

And Vue will recognize it as a regular native `input` evnet.

Comment: This is very efficient